# Laravel notification toArray() not saving data to notifications table

Tags: laravel-notification

I am unable to get database notification option to work. No information is saved to the database, there's no error and nothing shows on Laravel Telescope.

This is my notification code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;

class LoginNotification extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable;

    /**
     * The user instance.
     *
     * @var \App\Models\User
     */
    public $user;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail', 'database'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
            ->greeting('Hello ' .$this->user->first_name.',')
            ->line('There has been a login event on your account.')
            ->line('If this was you, no further action is required.')
            ->line('If not, please reset your password using the button below and consider enabling two-factor authentication on your account')
            ->action('Reset Password', url('/forgot-password'));
    }

    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            'user' => $this->user->id,
            'ip' => session('ip_address'),
        ];
    }
}
```

The email gets sent but no data is saved to the notifications table. And only 'mail' is listed as a channel, 'database' isn't despite being there.

I'm at a loss on what the problem could be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work by changing my queue connection to 'sync'. So the problem was because my queue connection was previously 'database'. I was using this and running a queue worker. So my question should be how to get toArray method to work when queue connection is set to database.

UPDATE:
There's no issue here, all I needed to do was stop and restart the queue worker after my code changes.