# How do I use Laravel notification toArray or toDatabase method with 'database' queue connection

Tags: laravel-queue, laravel-notification

I asked this question: [Laravel notification toArray() not saving data to notifications table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70058124/laravel-notification-toarray-not-saving-data-to-notifications-table/70058431#70058431) and afterwards, I just thought to change my queue connection back to 'sync' from 'database' and I found out that the toArray method saved to the notifications table.

I'm not sure there's anything in the docs under notifications or queues about a specific queue connection to use with the toArray or toDatabase methods.

Is it that these methods don't work with 'database' queue connection or there's something else I need to do to make them work together?

Answer (score 1):

Clear the cache of your application

```
php artisan optimize:clear
```

Comment: I actually sorted this using php artisan cache:clear.